# Matlab "quadprog" quadratic programming does not give desired solution when using greater values?

Tags: optimization, matlab, quadratic-programming

I have a control system problem which requires to solve quadratic programming to minimize quadratic cost function under inequality constraints.

[image]

The aim is to find control input increments which minimize the cost function.

For the first case, my inputs are relatively small values like 20 [N] and 150 [Nm] and the error between the current state and reference state is calculated by the terms in parenthesis where the reference values have 0.1 [m] increment.

When I map the inputs to new sets of inputs having relatively large values like 9810 [rpm^2] for nominal value and 25000 [rpm^2] for maximum value, quadratic programming outputs really small values which does not affect the system as much as it requires. So, it stays where it started in equilibrium point.

Is there anything that I should consider about the magnitudes of the quantities used in cost function or quadratic programming?

Comment: Perhaps it's just that I don't know anything about the type of problem that this question seems very unclear. Without understanding the details, I will just discuss for a general problem
$$\min_x \frac{1}{2}x^THx+f^Tx.$$ In this case, you could presumably get numerical issues when $H$ is ill-conditioned, and you could get bad solutions (local solutions) if the problem is non-convex, i.e., $H$ is not positive (negative) semidefinite.

Comment: Hi, @David I will check the matrix in any case. Actually, this is a state-space represented system control with MPC(Model Predictive Controller) controller which inherits some calculations from LQR control. Thus, it has some penalty matrices to limit the inputs or outputs. I have made some search after you told maybe the characterizations of the matrices could be the reason and found that the R matrix which penalizes the inputs can have weighting numbers less than 1 which allows the quadratic solution to be greater by less penalizing inputs. Now I have other problems related with the dynamics.